# python 2.7 working with zip files

Tags: python, zip

An interesting problem occurred to me while working with a zip file.
With one zip file everything works ok, while the other zip file that is suppose to be the same (the files in it are the same to the dot looking them in hexadecimal view).

But with one file I get an error

`(<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>, 
UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', '\xef\xbb\xbbegin penalites....)`

I am using `python 2.7`

This is the code

```
   dtacont  = unicode(z.read(datoteka),'utf-8').replace("\r","").split("\n").
```

This is where program stops. I am using zipfile package.
If you want the files let me know where to host them.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: First of all, we need code. Second, could you host the files somewhere so we can doublecheck?

Comment: This is the code 
dtacont  = unicode(z.read(datoteka),'utf-8').replace("\r","").split("\n"). This is where program stops. I am using zipfile package. Where do you want me, or where can I host the files?

Comment: @Yebach Edit your question, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: Try commenting out your `try-except` stuff and post the real error message and stack trace here. The string in question is valid utf8, so it cannot be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I'd guess there is more coming after the ... that contains non utf-8. You could post whatever z.read(datoteka) gives you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with reading the zip, but the content of your zip file seems to contain non utf-8 characters and the decode(unicode(...)) fails because of that.